# Global Namespace documentation

Tags: temporal-workflow

*A newbie to Temporal*

I wanted to learn about the Disaster Recovery capabilities of Temporal Framework.

From the [docs](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/server/namespaces/), It looks like Temporal provides a way to failover to other cluster using the namespaces -- A global namespace.
What the documentation does not provide is ways to configure a multi cluster environment under a global namespace.

Any leads for documentation / blog posts / videos that talk about Global Namespaces?